# how to replace the columns and rows in a csv using panda

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .data file and converted it into a csv file, but now I have a table with two rows and 20 columns. How can I convert it into a table with 20 rows and two columns?

Comment: Use `out = df.T`

Comment: you can use numpy tranpose from 2x20 to 20x2. Let's say a parameter as named data. you need to ` data_transposed = data.T ` . After that you can create a pandas dataframe like pd.DataFrame(data=data_tranposed,columns=your_cols)